# Javascript regular expressions match alphabetical or -

Tags: javascript, regex

I wanna catch words that begin with an uppercase followed with either [a-b] or - but it don't seem to work.
Here my regular expression I tried ^[A-Z][-[a-z]]
How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra set of brackets in there:

```
var str = "A-abcd";
var str2 = "AA-abcd";

var patt = new RegExp("^[A-Z][-a-z]");
var res = patt.test(str);
console.log(res);  // True

var res = patt.test(str2);
console.log(res);  // False
```

Answer (score 1):

You're close. You just have one too many sets of square brackets.

```
/^[A-Z][a-z\-]/
```